# Is there a way to find limits of integration numerically for triple integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I can do double integrals changing order of integration very easily because the drawing of graph is fairly easy in 2 dimensions and I use the graph to help me with finding limits of integration for double integrals when I am changing order of integration but when it comes to triple integrals I have a hard time visualizing or graphing the variables effectively enough to find the bounds....

So I wanted to ask if there is a way to find limits of integration after switching order of integration for triple integrals.